# how to add # before tags?

Tags: tags, template-tags

Like Lifehacker and several other sites, would like to know how to add # before tags displayed on the site.
for e.g. instead of a tag like "abc", how about "#abc". - is there a way to automatically add # across all the tags present in the system?

Comment: Global changes are usually overly broad and can cause unwanted issues. It is better practice to determine specific parts of theme where this should be applied, relevant function and work from there.

Comment: Yes. In single.php - this is precisely where I want to add this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add # before each tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105794/add-before-each-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do cosmetic changes on your theme with some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.tags li a').prepend('#');
});
</script>

<ul class="tags">
    <li><a href="/tag/sometag/">sometag</a></li>
</ul>
```