# Add # before each tag

Tags: tags

How can we add `#` before each tag with both [`the_tags( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)
and [`wp_tag_cloud( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud)?

Comment: Note: We need this, because without a hash a tag is worthless.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Another very simple solution is to put this in your css file :

```
.tagcloud a:before {
  content: "#";
  font-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use your own custom function, the_tags( ) doesn't allow you to do that.
You could create a function like this, using get_the_tags, and format your html as you prefer :

```
function hashtags() {
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '">#' . $tag->name . '</a> '; 
        }
    }
}
```